# Inspecting the contents of an array in the Xcode debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

Let's say I create an array:

```
NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", @"sdfsf", nil];
```

In Xcode, when I stop at a breakpoint and inspect `newArray` I see that it says "3 Objects", yet when I click the disclosure triangle all I see is one `NSObject` and there seems to be no way to see what that array contains.

In practice I am working with an array of custom objects and it is a royal pain to see the nesting or inspect the properties of them.

Can anyone provide some insight on a better way to use this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If it is in scope you can just type

```
po newArray
```

into the debugger and it will print the description.

Or if you prefer clicking things then just right click the object in the left panel pof the console and then click "Print Description of ..."

Comment: Even better, `po [myArray objectAtIndex:10]` will also work, as will `po [[myArray objectAtIndex:10] someProperty]`.

Comment: or po [myArray[10] someProperty]

Answer (score 0):

i'm a fan of NSLog.  you should be too :)

```
NSLog(@"contents of newArray: %@", newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just below line will do.

NSLog(@"%@", newArray);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).